# C# Read XML inside tag (Inner?)

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq-to-xml, xelement

Ok,  I have a small issue reading one of my company's notorious malformed xml files.

Trying to get 5 values from it and save them individually as variables.

Here is an example of the tricky XML.
(I may not be using the right terms, but I couldn't find anything on reading values of this type)

```
<ONE>
    <TWO>
      <THREE>
      </THREE>
    </TWO>
  <DATA internalid="1" externalid="2" lastname="lname" firstname="name" date="20.03.2003"/>
</ONE>
```

So, the data I need is internalid, externalid, lastname, firstname, and date.

What I've been working with so far, and unable to make anything happen.

```
string xml = (@"C:\1.xml");
var xmlElement = XElement.Load(xml);
var xmlList = (from message in xmlElement.Elements("DATA")
               select new
               {
                   internalid = message.Attribute("internalid").Value,
                   externalid = message.Attribute("externalid").Value,
                   lastname = message.Attribute("lastname").Value,
                   firstname = message.Attribute("firstname").Value,
                   date = message.Attribute("date").Value
               }).ToString();
```

And I'm unable to get it to fly.  Not that I'm getting any errors,  but when I out this string to a richtextbox or just textbox I get this....

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,<>f__AnonymousType0`5[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]

Also,  so I can better research the problem,  what is it called when data is INSIDE the tag like that?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Well yes, you're calling `ToString()` on a sequence. What did you expect the result to be, and why? This doesn't look like an XML problem at all to me. Additionally, please pay more attention to the formatting of your code in posts - there's no need for all that indentation.

Comment: You should apply method `ToString()` directly to XElement object, or create custom type instead of using anonymous classes with overriden ToString. But anyway you 'll get enumerable as output of your linq query. You can apply something like `String.Join(linqResult.Select(x=>x.ToString()))`

Comment: Got it now,  switched the out from ToString to ToList....  Got a nice output from that.  And it works.   Now working on getting this list into individual strings or vars....

Comment: Jon Skeet,  that's not very constructive or warranted.  It's just as bad to admonish a new member for using such methods.   We can all read it.  Who cares about some editing for clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jon Skeet mentioned you are calling ToString() on a sequence. The following code may get your closer to your desired solution.

```
var xmlList = (from message in xmlElement.Elements("DATA")
                select new
                {
                    internalid = message.Attribute("internalid").Value,
                    externalid = message.Attribute("externalid").Value,
                    lastname = message.Attribute("lastname").Value,
                    firstname = message.Attribute("firstname").Value,
                    date = message.Attribute("date").Value
                });

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in xmlList)
{
    builder.Append(item);
}
string test = builder.ToString();
```

As for your question regarding "data is INSIDE the tag like that". These are examples of [XML Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp).

Here's a good resource to start learning linq [Introduction to LINQ Queries (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with how you've read the data and saved to variables.  To display your data, instead of trying to convert the xmlList object to a string, just iterate through your list to output your data.

```
string xml = (@"C:\1.xml");
var xmlElement = XElement.Load(xml);
var xmlList = (from message in xmlElement.Elements("DATA")
        select new
        {
            internalid = message.Attribute("internalid").Value,
            externalid = message.Attribute("externalid").Value,
            lastname = message.Attribute("lastname").Value,
            firstname = message.Attribute("firstname").Value,
            date = message.Attribute("date").Value
        });

StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var xmlRecord in xmlList)
{
    string outputRecord = 
        string.Format("internalid: {0}, externalid: {1}, lastname: {2}, firstname: {3}, date: {4}", 
        xmlRecord.internalid.ToString(), xmlRecord.externalid.ToString(), 
        xmlRecord.lastname.ToString(), xmlRecord.firstname.ToString(),
        xmlRecord.date.ToString());
    outputString.AppendLine(outputRecord);
}
Console.WriteLine(outputString.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```